# RelativeLayout en IOS

Tags: ios, swift2

Tengo una app en Android y la necesito hacer en IOS.
En la app hay pantallas con formularios largos que ocupan bastante mas del largo de la pantalla, los cuales los hago en un layout xml, todo con código, usando relative layout.

¿Hay alguna forma en IOS de hacerlo de una manera parecida? De momento solo he usado el Interface Builder y con eso no puedo hacer lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada no intentes pensar como lo haces al programar para Android cuando estás programando para iOS, ya que las cosas funcionan diferente.

Si como dices, los elementos que necesitas incluir ocupan mas del largo de la vista, deberías de utilizar un `UIScrollView` y dentro de este posicionarlos para que sin importar el tamaño del dispositivo, los elementos se puedan ver haciendo `scroll` en la pantalla.

Por otra parte, no es obligatorio que utilices `Interface Builder` para crear tus elementos, estos los puedes crear programáticamente de una forma muy sencilla dentro de métodos como `viewDidLoad` de tu `UIViewController`.

Podrías incluso utilizar ciclos como en este ejemplo con `Swift`:

```
class MyAwesomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let numberOfLabels: Int = 100
        let labelHeight: CGFloat = 50

        let myAwesomeScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        myAwesomeScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.width, CGFloat(numberOfLabels) * labelHeight)

        for index in 1...numberOfLabels {
            let labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(index - 1) * labelHeight, myAwesomeScrollView.bounds.width, labelHeight)
            let myAwesomeLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

            myAwesomeLabel.text = "My awesome label \(index)"
            myAwesomeScrollView.addSubview(myAwesomeLabel)
        }

        view.addSubview(myAwesomeScrollView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

En `iOS` se utiliza el `Interface Builder`, no hay similitud con los `Relative Layout` de `Android`. Yo he hecho una app en `iOS` y en `Android` y no he podido utilizar nada de una app para otra.

Comment: Y si por ejemplo quiero poner 50 labels una debajo de otra, pero en el view controller solo caben 20?

Comment: Para eso existent los `UItableView` en `iOS`